# Error while running Memsql pipeline with transform using python script

Tags: singlestore

I tried to create a Memsql pipeline with transform as simple python script.But I got the below error

### Transform STDERR:

ImportedOS::ExecuteSubprocessAsync() subprocess /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3306/data/./transforms/340f7cf784f72c9d2146dcda4aedce06b4d19cf6/e451960fa0f67abdd1857449d59207ded723b43c/43b48daf174935ac7dc580587c60e6b235500af7/083982454f84a0aad8216a924cd57458e8c3d061_transform exited with failure result (13 : Permission denied)

When I checked for the corresponding transforms path, I don't see those paths in leaf nodes. I used the python scripts which are available in Memsql Doc.

Comment: Can you include your create pipeline statement?  Also did you provide the transform script directly or is it contained in a tarfile?

Comment: I am creating Memsql pipeline through WebUI . I am directly selecting .py script .I was trying to process Avro format first and got this error. So I tried for csv format and used the script provided by memsql in memsql docs and got the same error.

Comment: Whatever the path mentioned in the error I don't see that path in the leaf node(/var/lib/memsql/leaf-3306/data/./transforms/340f7cf784f72c9d2146dcda4aedce06b4d19cf6/e451960fa0f67abdd1857449d59207ded723b43c/43b48daf174935ac7dc580587c60e6b235500af7/083982454f84a0aad8216a924cd57458e8c3d061_transform).

Comment: Your script should start with a "shebang" line, and you should make sure python in installed and the shebang points to the right place.  Also, if you are on windows, beware copying-and-pasting code from browsers, as it  might insert \r\n line breaks which can confuse the linux based memsql.

Comment: I used the correct shebang line and also python installed on memsql. I saved python script on desktop and browsing the script from the desktop for transform. Not sure why it is throwing permission denied error. When I tried creating the path on memsql and root user ,I am able to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mounted file system has exec permission.(mount)
If it does not have, remount it with exec.(mount -o remount,exec /var)